# Elements of the dual space of X

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

For my course of functional analysis I came across the following question:

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space.
>
> Show that for every closed linear subspace $\subseteq X$ and $x \in X \backslash Y$, there exists $x'\in X'$ such that
>
> $x'|Y = 0$, $x'(x) \neq 0$

I came up with the following, but then I don't need to use the closedness of $Y$. So I wonder where I've gone wrong or where I need that $Y$ is closed. In a previous exercise we have shown that:

$$ \forall x \in X,  \ ||x|| = \sup \bigg\{ |x'(x)| \bigg | x' \in \bar{B}^{X'}_1(0) \bigg\}$$

Here is my proof:

Take $ x \in X \backslash Y$. Since $Y$ is a linear subspace we know that $x \neq 0$. Since $X$ is a normed space we know that $||x|| \neq 0$ and thus there exists a $\tilde{x}' \in \bar{B}^{X'}_1(0)$ s.t. $\tilde{x}'(x) \neq 0$

Now we define the following map:

$$  x'(x)= \begin{cases} \tilde{x}' (x), \ \mathrm{if} \  x \in X \backslash Y \\ 0, \ \mathrm{if}\  x\in Y  \end{cases}$$

This map is clearly linear and has the desired properties.

Comment: "clearly linear"?

Comment: "This map is clearly linear": no, it is not. Example: $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, $Y$ is the vertical axis, $x=(1,1)$ and $\tilde x'=x_1+x_2$.

Comment: I don't see why this map isn't linear. $\tilde(x) '$ is a element of the dual space thus it's a linear map

Comment: @A.G. I don't think that this $\tilde{x} '$ lies in the unit ball, since $\tilde{x} ' (1/ \sqrt{2} , 1/\sqrt{2}) = \sqrt{2}$, but I see where the map I defined doesn't work

Comment: @DeanTheMachine OK, normalize it. Still it is just piecewise linear, not linear, in general. The problem is to find a special continuation $\tilde x$ that makes it linear.

Comment: @A.G. Yes thank you, I understood that normalization is enough to make your example work. I just wanted to double check whether my thoughts were correct. Thank you for pointing out that it's not clearly linear, I was so busy worrying about the completeness that I just assumed I found a linear map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Hahn-Banach Theorem. First you can construct a linear function $f$ on the space $Y+\{x\}=\{u=y+\alpha x\mid y\in Y,\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\}$, such that $f(u)=\alpha$ if $u=y+\alpha x$. The you can extend this functional to $x' \in X$ on the whole space $X$ by Hanh-Banach Theorem.